Gmock: Sequence calls inside of a block with arbitrary block order
My productive code
Consider this interface:
class Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface = default;

    virtual void open(int id) = 0;
    virtual void close() = 0;

protected:
    // Default other special members here
};

Note that close() may only be called after an open() and close() must have been called before the next call to open(). IDs should not repeat.
Now I got some hard coded IDs and I need to call open() and close() for every ID respecting the aforementioned requirements. A correct implementation would be:
void actCorrect(Interface & interface)
{
    interface.open(1);
    interface.close();
    interface.open(2);
    interface.close();
    interface.open(3);
    interface.close();
}

The order of the IDs is not important, so the following code would be acceptable as well:
void actCorrect2(Interface & interface)
{
    interface.open(2);
    interface.close();
    interface.open(1);
    interface.close();
    interface.open(3);
    interface.close();
}

However, the following code should fail because the call close() is not sequenced between open(1) and any subsequent open(_):
void actWrong(Interface & interface)
{
    interface.open(1);
    interface.open(2);
    interface.open(3);
    interface.close();
    interface.close();
    interface.close();
}

Note: This is not a good implementation, but that is not the point. I chose it to make a point, to be able to deliberately add a bug with almost no difference in the code.
Robust tests wanted
I now want to write tests with GTest/GMock in such a way that the tests are robust against a order changing refactoring. To be explicit, the tests should:

still succeed if I changed the order of the open()/close() pairs. (see actCorrect() vs actCorrect2())
break if the open()/close() pairs are torn apart such that they are not subsequent calls on an Interface instance anymore. (see actWrong())

I'm skipping the mock definition (it should be obvious) and assume a using namespace ::testing; for the following code snippets.
To achieve requirement 2 I could use an InSequence object like so:
MockInterface mock;
InSequence const seq;
EXPECT_CALL(mock, open(1));
EXPECT_CALL(mock, close());
EXPECT_CALL(mock, open(2));
EXPECT_CALL(mock, close());
EXPECT_CALL(mock, open(3));
EXPECT_CALL(mock, close());
act(mock);

But this does not fulfill requirement 1, actCorrect2() will break this test.
Instead I could use a Sequence objects like so:
void expectOpenClose(MockInterface & mock, int const id)
{
    Sequence const seq;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, open(id)).InSequence(seq);
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, close()).InSequence(seq).RetiresOnSaturation();
}

TEST(Fixture, ActCorrect)
{
    MockInterface mock;
    expectOpenClose(mock, 1);
    expectOpenClose(mock, 2);
    expectOpenClose(mock, 3);
    actCorrect(mock);
}

This will accept actCorrect() and actCorrect2() thus fulfilling requirement 1 but it will also accept actWrong(). This is because I did not tell GMock that each sequence must be finished before the next is started. (because I don't know how)
The best I can come up with is introducing state to track the current id and throw if it does not match:
MockInterface mock;
bool isOpen{ false };
EXPECT_CALL(mock, open(_)).WillRepeatedly(InvokeWithoutArgs([&]()
    {
        if (isOpen)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error{ "Calling open() but is not closed" };
        }
        isOpen = true;
    }));
EXPECT_CALL(mock, close()).WillRepeatedly(Invoke([&]()
    {
        if (!isOpen)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error{ "Calling close() but is not opened" };
        }
        isOpen = false;
    })); 

But in reality there are some more calls between the open()/close()-pairs and I would have to set up a similar action for all of them, which also kind of feels like partly re-implementing the logic. If I wanted to avoid duplicate IDs I would need to keep track of those as well which further complicated things.
Any ideas how to achieve this within the GMock framework? Ideally with one of the sequencing operations like .InSequence() or .After().
The code presented here can be seen live on Compiler Explorer

I think your problem is mainly related to a design issue (if writing a unit test is hard, it usually is a design issue). And if open/close should match on id then I miss a RAII object that will call open/close for you (and which you can test seperatatly).

Works for me: https://godbolt.org/z/GGeYYd6Kc

Or better demo that it works as desired: https://godbolt.org/z/Mf8389Mdj

@PepijnKramer Getting it implemented correctly is not the problem. It's tests that don't put to strict requirements on my code that are the problem. After all, the RAII object might someday be removed/replaced for whatever reason.

@MarekR Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't get it. I looked at the better demo and in act() the close(0) comes last not second, so every test should fail. I think that I should remove actWithId() from my question and rather show a good and a bad implementation. I changed your suggestion to show that it does not work. actBad should fail but does not. Basically it's the same as my example how to use Sequence objects, and I also explain why it does not work.

@MarekR I revised my question in the hope to make my problem clearer. I removed actWithId() which is already an implementation detail. Instead I now use the worst possible but correct implementation which makes it easy to introduce a bug which my tests should detect. I pasted my 3 implementations into your code and actWrong() is not detected.

I realised that close() does not expect the id in my real code, so I removed it.
Without it there is no way to discern the close() calls so I had to add .RetiresOnSaturation() to make it work, see here. This could probably be dropped if the correct sequence could be taught to GMock.

I understand the urge to use gmock features for sequencing, but IMHO they are not good tools for your case. You should write tests that directly test your requirements, and from your post I understand that these are:

close() may only be called after open()


close() must have been called before the next call to open()


IDs should not repeat.

For that I would write a small simulator of your device/network/connection that you are interfacing, to keep the open/closed state and the IDs that were already used (so, your last idea expanded a bit):
    bool isOpen{false};
    std::unordered_set<int> ids;
    MockInterface mockIFace;
    EXPECT_CALL(mockIFace, open(_)).WillRepeatedly(Invoke([&](int id){
        if (isOpen) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Already open");  // or design your custom exception
        }
        if (ids.count(id)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Id already used");
        }
        isOpen = true;
        ids.insert(id);
    }));
    EXPECT_CALL(mockIFace, close()).WillRepeatedly(Invoke([&](){
        if (!isOpen) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Not open");
        }
        isOpen = false;
    }));

That code could be put in the test fixture body to make sure the states are reset before each testcase execution. Then you can test it by simply executing your system:
    MySystem ms{mockIFace};
    ms.exec();  // does some sequence of open/close actions

and if the sequence of open/close violates any of the rules, the test will exit with exception. To be more explicit you can
    ASSERT_NO_THROW(ms.exec());

or:
    try {
        ms.exec();
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        printSomeDiagnostics(e.what());
        FAIL();
    }

or if you have some method that SHOULD violate the rules, then you can ASSERT_THROW(ms.badAction(), /* some exception matcher */); .
I think this approach clearly shows your intent and is way more readable than trying to hack it around with InSequence, Times, RetiresOnSaturation etc.

Thanks for your answer, I was already starting to accept this fact. Also, I mentioned that in my real code there are other functions that I call in between, but these can be handled with a Sequence struct.
